# LLAMA 2 in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I deployed `llama-2` `13B` and `70B` in Vertex AI through Model Garden. Deployment was successful, but when I am hitting the endpoint through `curl` I keep on getting below error. Has anyone tried `llama-2` in Vertex AI?

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "Took too long to respond when processing endpoint_id: {endpoint_id}, deployed_model_id: {deployed_model_id}",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can someone guide me on what steps should I do in order to access this model Via API and what are the possible ways to stream the response from the model such that it looks like the response is generated in real-time?

Comment: I would try to stay with the 13b model till everything works and then try to deploy the 70b model. What machine have you chosen and do you see anything in the logs of the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

The message you've received signifies a "503 Service Unavailable" error, which means that, at the time of the request, the server responsible for hosting your machine learning model's endpoint was temporarily incapable of processing the query. Make sure that the configuration of your deployed model aligns with your use case and workload, including considerations such as the machine type, scaling preferences, and GPU setup.

"LLAMA-2" with **13 billion or 70 billion** parameters is a very large model. Larger models typically require more computational resources. Ensure that the selected machine type has enough memory to accommodate the model. For the `13 billion` parameter model, you might consider a standard machine with **4 vCPUs and 16 GB of RAM** as a starting point. However, for the 70 billion parameter model, you would likely need a more powerful instance with more CPU and memory. Look for machine types with **32 GB** or more RAM.. Also, consider using GPU machine types, such as the NVIDIA Tesla series, which can accelerate deep learning workloads significantly.

Comment: If you would get the 70b model to run on CPU, the response would be beyond 10 minutes. Vertex AI Online Prediction has a standard timeout of 1 minutes. So 70b model on Vertex AI Online Prediction without GPU won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue using llama 70b. I believe the model is too big for the available machines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).